# Huge table (9 million records) in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

Our underwriting company just sent us a data extract of leads.  There are 9 million rows.  The rows consist of LeadID (guid), RawLeadXML (xml -- probably 3-4kb max), and a LeadStatusID (int).

I first tried to add an autonumber integer and make it the primary key of this table.  Well, it added the field, but couldn't make it the primary key (There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool.)

What I need to do is to take every record, 1 by 1, and get the XML, put it into an XmlDocument object in .Net, strip out all the fields I want (firstname, lastname, etc) and store that parsed information into another table.

I can't even get this statement to run:  select * from Leads where id between 1 and 1000

If I just select 1000 records at a time (select top 1000 * from Leads), that works, but how would I then select the next 1000 records without some sort of reference point?

My machine has 4 processors (2.53Ghz) and 12 GB of RAM.  It's not a server, but it's a beefy machine.  I don't know what to try next, honestly.

**EDIT**:  I left out that the original file was actually an MDF (and the associated LDF) file, so I just attached to them in SQL Server.

**EDIT 2**: I messed up and said that the RawLeadXML column was XML -- it isn't, it's just nvarchar(max).  I honestly didn't know there WAS an xml datatype.

**EDIT 3**:  I can't even issue a delete statement on this table:  "delete from leads where leadid = '100a7927-5311-4f12-8fe3-95c079d32dd4' " blows up with:

```
Msg 802, Level 17, State 20, Line 2
There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool.
```

I have no idea what to do next.  How in the hell is this even a problem?  There are thousands of databases in the world with more records than I've got.

**EDIT 4**:  In case anyone cares, none of the below solutions worked.  I'm sure this is a limitation of my machine, and definitely not a condemnation of the fine answers I received below.  Currently, I am transferring the zipped DB (2.6 GB) to our servers in Rackspace, and then I will attempt to add an index on that hardware, hopefully without taking down our production servers.  Once the index is added, I'm hopeful that I can zip up the db and bring it back down to my local machine, and then be able to actually do something with it.

**EDIT 5**:  My machine was literally incapable of handling a table of this size.  My machine has 12 GB RAM, 64 bit Windows 7 Professional, a quad core 2.53Ghz processor, SSD drive, etc.  It's pretty beefy for a development machine.  And it couldn't handle this.

So, I moved the DB to our server in Rackspace in London.  48 GB or memory in that one, and it was able to add the index I needed.  Even after that, my machine here was unable to do anything all that useful with it, so I've written a .Net program that is running in London to put out the records 1000 at a time, parse them into another table, and then mark the original records as processed.

Once I do this, I'm going to have to leave the DB in London, because I doubt I could write any meaningful reports against this monstrosity locally.  Which will make development fun.

**Summary**:  I believe that there is no good way to process a dataset this large without using server class hardware with at least 48 GB of RAM (in my case).

Comment: Does doing a select without a where clause, start returning rows?  If so, that would appear to be an option.  If not, do you still have the original text file?  Would it be easier to process that file directly, rather than having to work with the database?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question.  There wasn't a CSV or anything, they were mdf and ldf files.

Comment: but the rawlead column, is there xml in teh nvarchar max?

Comment: Yes.  The RawLeadXML column is type of nvarchar(max) and it contains all XML.  Not always valid XML, but it is xml nontheless.  Just stored as text, not as an XML type of column.

Comment: Have you tried whats in here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx. There is something about memory error 802 one third down in the document.

Comment: Yeah, it says see error 701, which then tells you to follow the steps here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx#_General_troubleshooting_steps_in ca  I've gone through some of these, but a lot of the techniques assume a server that is being hit by outside forces, and this is my lonely local dev machine, without any other things running (browser and some other startup stuff), but nothing crazy, just after a reboot.  I'll still try all of those items.

Comment: It still is intriguing problem. Thanks for the update. Any luck yet? Can't you process the data at Rackspace? Sorry we could not offer a solution.

Comment: @Jacco -- once the data was at Rackspace, I was able to add the index onto the table (and others, too).  It took 12 minutes.  I watched the memory usage on the server climb to 44 GB, out of 48 available.  I then detached it and zipped it and copied it back down.  I'm currently still running the program that I wrote to take the XML out of the table and split it up into it's distinct fields.  It is estimated to finish tomorrow evening.  My machine has been cranking for several days.  I will update the final results here after it's done.  Seriously, though, thanks for all the help.

Comment: @forsvarir added a bounty to this question, no me.  That was nice.  Thanks!  Although I don't think that this question is answerable until 48+ GB dev machines become the norm.

Comment: @Matt Dawdy: To be honest I expected there to be some configuration *magic* that could be performed to get it working.  I'm not sure what it's like in the SQL server world anymore, but in oracle world DBA != developer.  It may be that if there's a more relevant DBA stack exchange site (Server Fault?) they may be able to provide some configuration advice, or you could be right the only solution is more RAM..

Comment: @forsvarir -- good point.  And I am DEFINITELY not a DBA.  I know just enough to be very dangerous.  I did ask this on Server Fault, but only got 1 answer, and low activity.  I think those guys really want to deal with servers instead of dev machines.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

9 million rows is not that big, you probably don't have an index on LeadId column. First create one, though it will take some time (doesn't have to be unique or primary key). 
Than use a 
"SELECT TOP 1000 LeadId, RawXML ORDER BY LeadId" for first query. 
Record last LeadId (MaxLeadId) value, use 
"SELECT TOP 1000 LeadId, RawXML Where LeadId > MaxLeadId ORDER BY LeadId" 
and so on...

Comment: I might try this if the export to flat file then import into target table method doesn't work.

Comment: select top 1000 * from Leads order by leadid causes an buffer memory error, too.  I'll try to restart my machine and attempt it, but I'm 165k records into exporting it to a flat file to try a different approach first.

Comment: I'm adding a key now (the export got through only 200k records in 30 minutes, so, while I still might try that route again, I won't do it until I can start it and go home).

Comment: I'm adding a key now.  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Leads ON dbo.Leads(LeadID) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  Unfortunately there isn't a progress meter when creating a key.  My memory usage went from 2 GB (normal Idle memory usage of this machine) to 11.8GB.  Ran for 7 minutes then crapped out with "The statement has been terminated.

Comment: OK, so create another table with the same structure and index on primary key column. Dump you old table and load data to the new one. Expect it to take some time. But without indeces you are doomed.

Answer (score 9):

Error 802 does not mean out of memory in the classical sense of insufficient memory to do an allocation (that would trigger [error 701](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337311.aspx)). [Error 802](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337354.aspx) actually indicates that the buffer pool cannot grow, which can occur due to a couple of reasons:

- [max server memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180797.aspx) setting explicitly prevents buffer pool growth, check your server setting.
- x86 virtual address space limit is hit and [AWE is not enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190673.aspx). Check if you have an x86 (32 bit) instance and if yes, check if *all* the conditions to enable AWE are met.

If you still haven't found the problem, read [How to use the DBCC MEMORYSTATUS command to monitor memory usage on SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877/EN-US) (the article applies equally well to SQL Server 2008 and to 2008 R2) and follow the guidelines there to understand who/what is consuming your memory.

Comment: In my case creating a clustered index on a table with 160mil records was failing on this memory error message. Setting the maximum server memory to 4GB fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

Adding a column is not an option, since adding an auto-id didn't work either.
You migth want to store the altered/cleaned data in a new table.
This table may have an auto-id and separate columns for the data your extracting from the Xml.

After inserting data into this table, you can delete the original rows from the source table.
Or make a select statement, that excludes rows with a GUID that's already in the new table.

Since the rows of your source table have no depedency or specific order, the order in which you select / process your rows is not important.

Based on the comment, a suggestion for a SQL statement:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [source] [s] 
              WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [destination] [d] WHERE [d].[leadId] = [s].[leadId]))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [destination] ([leadId], [RawLeadXML], [LeadStatusId])
        SELECT TOP 100 [s].[leadId], [s].[RawLeadXML], [s].[LeadStatusId]
        FROM [source] [s] 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [destination] [d] WHERE [d].[leadId] = [s].[leadId])
END
```

I've set the number of records to insert at 100. That should spare your memory usage.

Comment: I did try that, but even "insert into NewTable(leadId, RawLeadXML, LeadStatusId) select leadId, RawLeadXML, LeadStatusId" generated an out of memory error.

Comment: I extended my answer. It seems like you were trying to insert all records at once?

Comment: Thank you for your time, Jacco -- I copied your statement above and replaced the values accordingly.  I'm watching my memory usage, and it is holding firm at 2 GB (not just SQL, but everything).  This may just work.  I'm assuming this will take a looooong time so I'll be sure to come back tomorrow, when, hopefully, it is finished.  It's been running for 25 minutes but there are no rows in the target table.  I'm assuming this is transactional?

Comment: Hmm, that's not as expected. If you only run the select statement? (select top 100 etc.) Does it return results, as expected? Did you add an index on the leadId-column?

Comment: Almost 16 hours later, the query is still running, memory usage have increased to 11 GB, but running a select (in a different query window) on the target table doesn't return any rows yet.  I can't add an index.  It fails with the memory buffer thing.  I think I might dump this database and restore from the pristine copy.  Then follow the instructions from "Remus Rusanu"s answer.  Then try all of this again.  What a pain.

Comment: I stopped the query.  It then spit out 9120 lines of "(100 row(s) affected)".  So, it was working.  In 16 hours, it got through 912k records (12% of my full table).  I'm going to restore the DB to factory fresh and try again, maybe moving the amount per loop to 1000.  Thanks for your help.  I'm not abandoning this, but it might take me a while to get back here and update due to how long it takes me to try all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have disk to spare?
Perhaps creating the same table structure in a "TableAux" but with an Autonumeric Id and then doing an insert from table...

Import into your TableAux from a flat file(Exporting it first if it's not a flat file), is another way to do so.

Getting an Id for your registers is priority to work with them.

Comment: Instead of an insert, he could use a merge, thats faster

Comment: I've got tons of disk space to spare.  I'm exporting to a flat file right now.  100k records in the past 30 seconds.  45 minutes or so with luck.

Comment: How did it go? Are you still in the export? Did you create that table? Are you importing?

Comment: Sorry -- the export was going to take 32 hours to complete (estimated by me, so may not be accurate).  I decided to kill it and start with another method for now -- but if that doesn't work, then I'm going to try exporting.  Actually, I'm trying your first suggestion right now, with code from Jacco's answer.  I'll keep checking here and updating with any solutions.  Unfortunately, with this particular problem, rapid testing isn't possible.

Comment: FYI -- export ran for 2 hours and exported close to 3 million records...then it died.  "There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool."  This is ridiculous.  Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: Try with a cursor, perhaps it may not use all the buffer, since it fetches to the cursor a record at a time. And don't use * _as in 'SELECT * FROM'..._ This is much less efficient than specifying every single field you need

Answer (score 1):

What about

- Select the first row (top 1) of the tabel, store the LeadID in a var.
- Load the value of the xml column into xml document (.NET)
- target the nodes that you need with xpath
- insert this values into a new record
- delete the record from the "main" table using the leadid (or mark it "done")
- commit
- Step 1 again

Comment: Top 1 wont necesarilly give him the first row in the database, it will be the first record in the dataset.  Don't think this will work everytime.

Comment: But, if I get the first TOP 1 (whatever it is) and then delete it, then getting the next TOP 1 should get another row since the first one I got was deleted, right?

Comment: I can't even delete 1 record from this table.  I literally mean that "delete from leads where leadid = '100a7927-5311-4f12-8fe3-95c079d32dd4' ; " fails with the "insufficient memory available in the buffer pool" error.  I'm completely out of ideas except for exporting the data to a file, and even then, I'm not sure how I would read in a line at a time and then delete the line, because the file will probably be 50GB+, and I'm not sure .Net will handle that.  Plus the XML in the file might span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Look into doing this by row_number() and ranks.

[Take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300047/divide-sql-server-table-int-chunks).  It has the basic concepts to get you started.

Comment: That has the requirement that sql can actually do an OVER (ORDER BY <column>).  I'm not sure if SQL can do that with this table (on my machine, I mean).  I can't test it right now due to running an export of the raw data.  But it's a great thought, and I'll try it if I can't get it to work with one of the other suggestions first.

Comment: Didn't work.  I tried this:
with Something AS
(SELECT leadid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY leadid) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM Leads
)
select * from Something where Rownumber between 10 and 20   and it blew up with msg 802, "There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool."

Answer (score 0):

If this is a flat file, could you perhaps get the first 1000 rows, load them and then go back and remove the rows from the file based off the GUID and then repeat? (Make a backup of the file first of course.)

Also you could try loading this file via an Integration Services package which should be able to track where it is at with the import and should be able to batch them and stay within your memory constraints.

Answer (score 0):

What format are you getting the extract in originally? If it's a csv or somesuch, and you don't care about the other information in that xml fragment, I'd use SSIS and skip this intermediate table entirely. The native XML type has some overhead associated with it that you don't need to incur if you're just looking to shred some xml once and then discard it.

Otherwise, you should be able to use XML path statements directly in a sql query to get the data from one table to another. If you're trying to add a new PK from the designer, it may well fail on a large table. You will need to script the changes and run them manually, and possibly tweak them to make things more efficient. Ultimately 9m rows isn't that huge by modern standards, but you do have to think things through more than with 9k.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question.  There wasn't a CSV or anything, they were mdf and ldf files.

Answer (score 0):

How about just extracting the data to a text file straight from the Access DB - then you can just import it into the RDBM of your choice with a bulk insert.

Getting to Access DBs via link tables in MSSQL is not ideal. Here we use a read-only, forward-only recordset cursor to walk through the rows one at a time.

This is VBScript, so it won't be the fastest, but it should work. You'll have to tailor the XML extraction routine for your schema.

```
' Code run against a access DB with column RawLeadXML

Dim connection

Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=d:\path\to\file.mdb;"

Dim recs

' By default this is a read only, forward only cursor
Set recs = connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM Leads")

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim out
Set out = fso.OpenTextFile("d:\path\to\output.txt", 2, True)

Dim id

id = 0

While Not recs.EOF
    id = id + 1 
    out.Write CStr(id) ' write an ID counter
    out.Write ","
    ExtractFieldsFromXML recs.Fields("RawLeadXML").Value, out
    out.Write Chr(10) ' Linefeed
    recs.MoveNext
Wend

out.Close
recs.Close
connection.Close

' Extract data from the XML and write it to the stream
' separated by commas
Sub ExtractFieldsFromXML(xml, out)
    Dim doc

    Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    MsgBox xml

    doc.loadXML xml

    out.Write doc.selectSingleNode("/xml/firstname").text
    out.Write ","
    out.Write doc.selectSingleNode("/xml/lastname").text

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but I couldn't export this to a text file.  I tried with SQL Server's built in data export tools, I tried with a C# program.  Nothing worked.  I doubt VBScript would fare any better.  It's just too big.

Comment: Did you try to export the data via the link in the SQL database, or straight from the JetDB? Size shouldn't matter, one row at a time ; I suspect that linking the table through MSSQL isn't treating the data one row at a time though - I think this is what's causing your buffer pool problems.

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page here.  There is no Access Database involved.  It's in SQL Server (I was given an mdf and ldf file, just attached it right to SQL).  Or are you saying that linking the table through Access then using the VBScript above might work better than the other things I've tried?

Comment: Hmmf. Possibly not. Maybe I thought "mdb" rather than "mdf". Comedy dyslexia strikes again....

Comment: :)  I totally understand.  And, it's worth a shot.  Not right now, as I've got our production machines cranking on this right now, but maybe if things calm down I'll try it as an exercise.